# Iteration with a variable in Python 2.7

Tags: python, file, loops, python-2.7

Hi experts I'm looking to make a loop of reading a text file then output (8) text files with the following code:

```
for i in range(1,9):
    with open(inputgui, 'r') as input1:
        junkinfo = [next(input1) for dummy in range(22)]
        with open(output, 'w') as output1:
            for line in input1:
                columns = line.strip().split()
                output1.write('{:8}{:8}\n'.format(columns[1], columns[i+1]))
```

Note that variable `inputgui` is a text variable from a user and output is a text variable from a user.  Example, the user in the gui will select `'C:/Data.txt'` and will want to name the output and iterate 8 times to produce `'C:/NewData1.txt'`, `'C:/NewData2.txt'`, etc.  How do I format variable `output` to iterate or most efficient way?

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  I realize I was combining string and integers together which is wrong big time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the user provides a file name with a .txt extension you can do this:

```
for i in range(1,9):
    with open(inputgui, 'r') as input1:
        junkinfo = [next(input1) for dummy in range(22)]

        newOutput = output[:-4] + str(i) + output[-4:]

        with open(newOutput, 'w') as output1:
            for line in input1:
                columns = line.strip().split()
                output1.write('{:8}{:8}\n'.format(columns[1], columns[i+1]))
```

If the extension is unknown you will need to find where the . is and splice based on its location

Answer (score 3):

The other answer(s) didn't mention it, but you can make the code more efficient and Pythonic by using the `list` function.

```
# Change
junkinfo = [next(input1) for dummy in range(22)]

# To
junkinfo = list(input1)[:22] 

# or even better...
junkinfo = list(input1)
```

If you don't need to trim it to 22 elements, you can use the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could create the output file name for any arbitrary file extension:

```
output_file = (str(i) + '.').join(output.rsplit('.', 1))
```

For example:

```
>>> output = r'C:\Some.File.Name.data'
>>> for i in range(1, 4):
...     print (str(i) + '.').join(output.rsplit('.', 1))
...
C:\Some.File.Name1.data
C:\Some.File.Name2.data
C:\Some.File.Name3.data
```